# What is the meaning of "ANSI as UTF-8" in Notepad++?

Tags: text, notepad++

I confused that the meaning of "ANSI as UTF-8" in Notepad++,
Is it means an **ANSI files** contained some characters that is identified as **UTF-8 encoding** in Notepad++ or else?

Answer (score 16):

It means it is saved as UTF-8 without the BOM (Byte Order Mark) and has already been flagged as misleading.

Please see:
http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4095/ (Page since removed)

The above bug report has been removed since the time of writing. It read as follows:

*“ANSI as UTF-8” is an incorrect, misleading and confusing term, which does not exist outside Notepad++.
In addition, it is inconsistent with the rest of the UI. Please replace it with the correct term “UTF-8 without BOM”.*

Comment: Thanks for your info, it's useful for me.

Comment: @JBES The link might be outdated - it is behind a "login-wall", ie. redirects to authentication page that should redirect to the actual page. (I don't have a SourceForge account, so I can't verify that.)

Comment: The project pages have changed. I have updated the answer.