# Files changing from UTF-8 to ANSI

Tags: python, utf-8, notepad++, ansi

I know a bit about computers, but this one has me puzzled.

Background: I am preparing to teach Python to Middle schoolers in an environment where I can't install Python. I'm trying to use an online IDE with Python built in, and storing .py files locally.

I am creating files at home, saving to a thumb drive, and accessing them at school using my school machine. When I save the files, they are showing as UTF-8, and I can close them and reload, and everything is fine. When I open them on my school machine, they are gobbledygook and are showing as ANSI. I have used several editors, primarily Notepad++ to work with the files. Notepad++ encoding is set to UTF-8, so I'm not sure where the ANSI is coming from. Using the Convert to UTF-8 feature in Notepad++ doesn't seem to do anything. I tried setting the file to read-only before transferring, but that doesn't seem to help. Going back to my home machine, the file is now ANSI and can't be opened on the machine that created it. I've also tried saving the file as a .txt with the same results.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Used Notepad, Notepad++, word, Thonny, Online-Python, Wing, and other editors.

Set Notepad++ Settings...Preferences...New Document to UTF-8 Apply to opened ANSI files

Comment: *"Going back to my home machine, the file is now ANSI and can't be opened on the machine that created it."* Does the file show as modified since the last time you were able to open it on your home machine? (you should be able to deduce that from the file timestamp)

Comment: What does the file contain?  "gobbledygook" isn't very descriptive.  For example, `s="print('马克')"` looks like `"print('é©¬å…‹')"` when the original is UTF-8 but *viewed* as Windows-1252 (a typical "ANSI" default for US and Western European Windows).  The file is still encoded as UTF-8, but the viewer is misinterpreting.

Comment: The technical term for gobbledygook is mojibake. That said, UTF-8 and ANSI are ways to interpret a byte sequence. Every UTF-8 byte sequence can be interpreted as ANSI, but not vice-versa. So, if any editor defaults to interpreting a file as ANSI, the correct way to fix that is to tell the editor the correct interpretation (a.k.a. encoding). Telling it to convert is definitely not what you want!

Comment: I suggest that when you open files (that works at home) on the school machine, and see that notepad++ shows ANSI as the encoding, you could right click on the "ANSI" part in status bar and change it to UTF-8. After this, the proper text should be displayed.

Comment: You should try do debug yourself. Try to create a python code with clearly Unicode (Use Latin, Greek, Indian, Chinese/Japanese words: copy them from Wikipedia articles, e.,g. on cities, and copy local name) (e.g. a python file with just one variable: a string. Check the size of such file, and check all steps the source code is flowing. Get where the error starts. Note: Python3 is UTF-8 by default, Web also. So you should really debug this (not just work-around) else you will have problems every time. Really.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all of the suggestions. I worked with this thing all morning and think I have found a solution.

Comment: Then I ejected the USB drive and the thumb drive, and reconnected them. The USB drive worked perfectly, but the files on the thumb drive showed up in gibberish ANSI. The creation dates and times were not changed. The only difference I could see between the USB drive and the thumb drive (other than physical) was that one was formatted in NTFS, while the other was exFAT (the thumb drive). I backed up the thumb drive (most of the reason why this took all morning) and reformatted it as NTFS.

Comment: Re-running my test with new test files worked as before, and after ejecting and reconnecting the thumb drive, it still worked perfectly. While I don't understand the nuts and bolts of the problem, this seems to be the solution.

Comment: Hmmm. I need to be less long-winded. What got truncated was that I created 12 test files using Notepad and Notepad++, 6 as .txt and 6 as .py, and saved them to the Desktop, a USB hard drive, and a thumb drive.

Comment: Interesting, sounds to me like something was corrupt on the thumb drive before (maybe in the FAT, if a reformat cleared it). Not sure why you didn't see this when you closed and reloaded the files without ejecting - maybe there's some caching which means the file can be "reloaded" without a read from the drive or maybe something was happening on eject to cause corruption.

Comment: This answers your question: [What is the meaning of "ANSI as UTF-8" in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977623/what-is-the-meaning-of-ansi-as-utf-8-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not record the encoding of a file in any way. It is up to the application opening the file to decide which encoding to use.

Applications such as Notepad try to guess the encoding by looking at part of the file. Sometimes they get it wrong.  The problem is that ANSI is always valid because there are no invalid byte values. But as you have noticed, being valid doesn't make it correct.

One convention used often in Windows is to start the file with a [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to indicate the file is UTF-8. Both Notepad and Python will recognize this and properly decode your file.